# Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `auth-postgres-srv`:`5432`

Tags: postgresql, dockerfile, nestjs, minikube, nginx-ingress

For learning proposes I'm trying to setup a development environment (micro-service architecture). at the first stage i want to setup an authentication service stack with NestJS, PostgreSQL.

here is the `gitHub` link for actual project: [Project](https://github.com/vgrigalashvili/microServices-with-NestJS)

While i'm tring to do migrations with `npx prisma migrate dev`, i'm getting error: `Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at auth-postgres-srv:5432`

I understand that my local machine where i'm executing this command cannot reach the actual database service in `minikube` cluster.

### I'll try to show u my setup and maybe someone can show me the right way to do particular setup.

Dockerfile

---

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

auth-depl.yaml

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: vgrigalashvili/auth
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  # type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

auth-postgres-depl.yaml

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-postgres-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth-postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth-postgres
          image: postgres
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: postgres
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres
                  key: POSTGRES_PWD
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: auth-db
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-postgres-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth-postgres
  ports:
    - name: db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
```

ingress-srv.yaml

---

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: microservices.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /v1/auth/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

skaffold.yaml

---

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: vgrigalashvili/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
```

.env

---

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:123321aA@auth-postgres-srv:5432/auth-db?schema=public"
```

ERROR! while executing: npx prisma migrate dev

---

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "auth-db", schema "public" at "auth-postgres-srv:5432"

Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `auth-postgres-srv`:`5432`

Please make sure your database server is running at `auth-postgres-srv`:`5432`.
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on the same project using **Prisma** in a **Kubernetes** cluster development environment and fall into the same kind of problem, my local machine couldn't access the database inside the cluster, so my solution was to run the command to update the database directly inside of the pod and worked out well, but instead of doing this manually I added a script in package.json to run this for me every time it compiles and starts/restarts the pod, like this:

```
"prestart:dev": "npx prisma db push --accept-data-loss && npx prisma generate"
```